# Orbital angular momentum and multielectron atoms energies

Tags: energy, angular-momentum

Explain why states with diﬀerent orbital angular momentum quantum
number have diﬀerent energies for multielectron atoms but are degenerate in energy for hydrogen

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1):

The degeneracy of the states with different orbital angular momenta is a special case and applies only for an inverse square law force. In a hydrogen atom the potential is just a Coulomb potential:

$$ V(r) = -k\frac{e^2}{r} $$

so the states are degenerate. In a multielectron atom the potential is:

$$ V(r) = -\sum_i k\frac{Ze^2}{r_i} + \sum_{i \ne j}k\frac{e^2}{r_{ij}} $$

where the extra term is due to the repulsion between the electrons. This is no longer the potential associated with an inverse square law, so the states with different orbital angular momenta are no longer degenerate.